What species of a spider is it?
I found this specimen in my garage in Idaho:

Does anyone know what species is it? Is it venomous?

My guess:
Schizocosa mccooki
You can go to the website inaturalist.org and set location and type of animal, then you can compare.
Its a type of wolf spider and has medically insignificant venom.
https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/230594-Schizocosa-mccooki
https://www.webmd.com/a-to-z-guides/what-you-need-to-know-about-a-wolf-spider-bite
https://pictureinsect.com/wiki/Schizocosa_mccooki.html
